# Is it possible to remove the preceding new lines and retain only the last newline?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on this problem but I cant make it work. See the code below and can someone give me modification about the query?

I want this insert statement to change from this

```
`Insert into Sample_Table
   (DESCRIPTION)
 Values
   ('This is example
test
TEST');`
```

into this when I view the insert statement of that data in the table:

```
`Insert into Sample_Table
   (DESCRIPTION)
 Values
   ('This is example test
TEST');`
```

Is it possible by using regular expression?

This is the query I'm using. Can someone modify this so I can come up with the expected output? Thanks in advance.

```
`DECLARE

CURSOR chk_for_bad_data IS
   SELECT description
     FROM Sample_Table 
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (replace(replace(description,chr(10), ';'), CHR(09), ';'), '[^[:print:]]', 'x');

BEGIN

   FOR get_bad_data IN chk_for_bad_data LOOP

       UPDATE Sample_Table 
       SET description = regexp_replace(description, '(.*)(\r?\n)+$', '\1\r\n');
       WHERE descriptio = get_bad_data.description
   END LOOP;     
END;`
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using oracle

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expressions and can use simple string functions to find the index of the last newline character and then replace all the newlines in the sub-string before that:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'This is example
test
TEST' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CASE
       WHEN INSTR(value, CHR(10), -1) = 0
       THEN value
       ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, CHR(10), -1) - 1), CHR(10), ' ')
            || SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, CHR(10), -1))
       END AS removed
FROM   data
```

Which outputs:

| REMOVED |
| --- |
| This is example test TEST |

---

Your query could then be simplified to (without the need for any cursor or loops):

```sql
UPDATE sample_table
SET description = CASE
                  WHEN INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1) = 0
                  THEN description
                  ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1) - 1), CHR(10), ' ')
                       || SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1))
                  END
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(description, '[^[:print:]]');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FbE0-Ive)

Answer (score 0):

You could first split the description into 2 parts:

1. up till the last newline:
   **SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1))**
2. starting from the last newline:
   **SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1))**

Then, remove all newlines from the first part:
**REPLACE(SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1)), CHR(10), '')**

And finally concatenate that resulting string and the initial 2nd part:
**REPLACE(SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1)), CHR(10), '') ||

SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1))**

This of course only for the elements that have at least 1 newline in the description.

For example:

```
UPDATE Sample_Table
   SET description = REPLACE(SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1)), CHR(10), '') || SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, CHR(10), -1))
 WHERE INSTR(description, CHR(10)) > 0;
```

Your code does something with 'tab' and 'return' characters as well. It was not specified in the question so I don't know what to do with that.

Maybe you want to insert a space where you remove a newline. In that case, change the last parameter of the REPLACE function from an empty string to a single space.